# Rails has_many relationship without using id

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Have been messing around with Rails and while going through Hartl's tutorial I was asked to do a project. Figured it was a good opportunity to deviate off of the path, even though I don't know enough ;) Hence why I'm having a few problems.

I have two models:

`Foo`, which has parameter name and `has_many FooStatus`

`FooStatus`, which has parameters Foo.name and content, belongs_to Foo

Hartl's tutorial uses accounts that you log into, thus the `@foo` parameter is already bound and `foo.id` would be readily available for use. Once authenticated, a user can create a status for any `Foo`. In my HTTP request I am trying to send over `foo.name` and `foostatus.content` and have that information save to my DB.

My questions: 
Will these models store the appropriate relationship / link between the two objects in the db?

The line `<% if @foo.foostatus.any? %>` is giving me the error

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: foostatus.foo_id: SELECT  1 AS one FROM "foostatus"  WHERE "foostatus"."foo_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1
```

so I'm assuming that the `.any?` method is looking for `foostatus.foo_id`, which I don't store in my table.

I had originally thought that I could say

```
foo = Foo.find_by_name(params[:name]) 
@foostatus = foo.foostatus.build(params[:content])
```

but reading about Strong Parameters threw me in a circle, in that this wouldn't be allowed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can specify which columns are to be used as foreign and primary key for association:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foo_statuses, foreign_key: :foo_name, primary_key: :name
end

class FooStatus < ActiveReocrd::Base
  belongs_to :foo, foreign_key: :foo_name, primary_key: :name
end
```

Comment: It took me a minute to realize I was missing those colons in front of foo_name, but I got it! ;) Many thanks good sir!