# querying another model in a rails model function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

Basically, what I'm trying to do is a join on a text field rather than an id like

```
SELECT country.delivery_time 
FROM order, country
WHERE order.country = country.name
```

and what I've got so far for my Rails models is

```
class Country < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :delivery_time, presence: true
end

class Order < ApplicationRecord
  validates :country, presence: true

  def shipping_time
    # want to get the correct country from the DB
    if self.country == country.name
      country.delivery_time
    else
      "unavailable"
    end
  end
end
```

where `shipping_time` is the function that should return the result of the join. The error I'm getting is

> undefined method `country'

I'm using Ruby 3.0.3 and Rails 7.0.0.

Comment: Does the `orders` database table have a column `country`? It looks like it does not because otherwise `self.country` should be defined. Did you run migrations and restart the server after adding that column? What does you `schema.rb` look like?

Comment: If we do not have a country methods defined in Order class - the line - ```if self.country == country.name``` is equivalent to ```if self.country == self.country.name``` what doesn't make much sense

Comment: i think there is a syntax for relation has many or belongs to without using id.
is this one help?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21466770/11544219

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up using the `joins` function to get what I wanted,

```
Order.joins("INNER JOIN countries ON orders.country = countries.name")
```

where the full function is

```
def shipping_time
  relation = Order.joins("INNER JOIN countries ON orders.country = countries.name")
  if 1 == relation.count()
    relation[0].delivery_time
  else
    "unavailable"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Breaking the conventions and using a foreign key column of any type is actually pretty straight forward:

```
class AddCountryNameToOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    add_column :orders, :country_name, :string
    # Some DB's may not allow foreign key constraints 
    # on non PK columns
    add_foreign_key :orders, :countries,
      column: :country_name,
      primary_key: :name
  end
end

class Order < ApplicationRecord
  validates :country, presence: true
  belongs_to :country, 
    foreign_key: :country_name,
    primary_key: :name
end

class Country < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :orders,
    foreign_key: :country_name,
    primary_key: :name
end
```

The column used as the `primary_key` option doesn't actually have to be the PK of the target table. Simply naming the column `country` would cause a name clash though unless you choose different name for the assocation (and make this into even more of a mess).

#### But given the domain its a very bad idea.

Countries do actually change names - recent examples are North Macedonia and Eswatini.

Instead just use a normal integer/uuid foreign key column and use delegation to get the name from the country.

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :country
  delegate :name, to: :country,
                  prefix: true
end
```

If you want to use a "natural" primary key for the table instead of a surrogate key (such as an autogenerated id) then the ISO 3166 country codes are a far better choice.